# Unable to create or extract archives in Ubuntu 12.04.5 Unity

Tags: 12.04, unity, filemanager, archive

Here's my problem:

I want to create/extract archives (like .zip or .tar.gz) from my file manager in Ubuntu 12.04.5 Unity. But when I right-click a file, the options simply are not there.

When I right-click a normal file, there is no option to "create archive" and when I right-click an archive, there are no options to "extract here" or "extract to".

Comment: if the option  Compress... for packing in an archive the context menu is not there you could check the Ubuntu Software Center if the 'archive manager' is installed or not.. you may want to install other compressors and extractors too.

Comment: What's your filemanager?

Comment: I have Nautilus installed as well as Thunar. I mostly use Thunar.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are using Nautilus, you have nothing else mentioned.

Install the archive manager *file-roller*:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall file-roller
```

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>

Type: `unity` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Turns out, the file-roller package wasn't even installed! So I installed it and it still did not work.

Comment: @It'sWillem Try to restart Unity.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that.

Comment: @It'sWillem Were you satisfied with my answer? Then give me a upvote (∧). If I could solve your problem, then it would be nice if you'd mark my answer (✓). ;)

Answer (score 0):

You may install this https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/thunar/ and reboot... It will create "extract here" kind of options

Comment: A reboot? Why that?

Comment: I'm already using Thunar. Nope.